# Decrypt an array of strings in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, encryption

I have an existing program that encrypts and decrypts a text file on a line by line basis (other functions within the application append encrypted lines to the file randomly so you can’t just encrypt the whole thing).

Occasionally I need to search through the entire encrypted file looking for a certain string, so at the moment I read all the lines of the file into an array I then loop through the array passing each element to the decryption function so I can search accordingly (example code below).

```
 Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("my file")

    Dim decryptedarray As New ArrayList
    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        decryptedarray.Add(DecryptString(objReader.ReadLine(), SystemKey))
    Loop
```

My main problem is that some of the files can be around 20000 lines long and while reading the lines into memory only takes a fraction of a second, the process of iterating through the array and decrypting each element is taking around 60 seconds which is a long time for a user to wait.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of performing an action on all elements of an array than just looping through it to try and improve the speed. Alternatively if anybody can offer up a more efficient decryption method (current method is below for your perusal), or in fact any comments on how to improve the speed this takes would be very welcome.

```
  Public Function DecryptString(ByVal vstrStringToBeDecrypted As String, _
                                    ByVal vstrDecryptionKey As String) As String

    Dim test As String = Len(vstrStringToBeDecrypted)
    Dim holder As String = vstrStringToBeDecrypted
    If Len(vstrStringToBeDecrypted) > 1 Then
        Dim bytDataToBeDecrypted() As Byte
        Dim bytTemp() As Byte
        Dim bytIV() As Byte = {some byte IV}
        Dim objRijndaelManaged As New RijndaelManaged()
        Dim objMemoryStream As MemoryStream
        Dim objCryptoStream As CryptoStream
        Dim bytDecryptionKey() As Byte

        Dim intLength As Integer
        Dim intRemaining As Integer

        Dim strReturnString As String = String.Empty

        Dim stringtodecrypt As String = LoadDBString(vstrStringToBeDecrypted)
        If Not stringtodecrypt = "" Then

            Try
                bytDataToBeDecrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(stringtodecrypt)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return ""
                Exit Function
            End Try

            intLength = Len(vstrDecryptionKey)

            If intLength >= 32 Then
                vstrDecryptionKey = Strings.Left(vstrDecryptionKey, 32)
            Else
                intLength = Len(vstrDecryptionKey)
                intRemaining = 32 - intLength
                vstrDecryptionKey = vstrDecryptionKey & Strings.StrDup(intRemaining, "X")
            End If

            bytDecryptionKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vstrDecryptionKey.ToCharArray)

            ReDim bytTemp(bytDataToBeDecrypted.Length)

            objMemoryStream = New MemoryStream(bytDataToBeDecrypted)

            Try

                objCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(objMemoryStream, _
                   objRijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor(bytDecryptionKey, bytIV), _
                   CryptoStreamMode.Read)

                objCryptoStream.Read(bytTemp, 0, bytTemp.Length)

                objCryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
                objMemoryStream.Close()
                objCryptoStream.Close()

            Catch

            End Try

            Return StripNullCharacters(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytTemp))
        Else
            Return ""
        End If

    Else
        Return ""
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: what encryption method are you using? 20k is a lot of strings, have you tried a background worker?  the other thing to consider is to wrap them in a class or List (or both) and decrypt each one as needed rather than when loaded.  if they are not all used all the time, you save time not decrypting unused ones.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Plutonix, I am using Rijndael encryption (full method above). I am currently playing with background workers as a possibility, I have created 2 workers one to do even numbered elements and one to do odd. This has improved the speed by around 15 seconds. When performing a search function all elements need to be decrypted or you cant tell if they contain the information you want so loading them when needed wont help much.